# How do these authors get to this result?

Tags: probability, finance, conditional-expectation

I am not sure if this question satisfies the guidelines, but here goes.

I'm reading a paper (text is below) from a financial mathematics journal, and the authors make a calculation step that I don't get. They reach the conclusion that $$E_i(\theta)=\frac{\alpha y + \beta x_i}{\alpha +\beta}$$

Whereas I would guess that the result should be either $$E_i(\theta)=y$$ or $$E_i(\theta):=E_i(\theta|x_i)=E_i(x_i)-E_i(\epsilon_i)=x_i$$

In the second case I'm interpreting the expectation as conditional expectation, and this seems to me the most sensible interpretation.

**However the author's result is completely different as you can see, and I have no idea how they get to that result**. In fact, if this weren't published in a peer reviewed journal, I would assume they made a very weird mistake. But since it's in a peer reviewed journal, I must miss something.

Here is the entire text:

> Here is some context:
>
> [image]
>
> Here is the part my question is about:
>
> [image]

**How do they get to this result?** How should I interpret the setup of their problem so that the conclusion makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

It's conditional expectation. The error in your calculation is assuming $\mathbb E_i(\epsilon_i)=0.$

One way to do the calculation is to notice that the variable $x'_i=\theta - (\beta/\alpha) \epsilon_i$ has zero covariance with $x_i=\theta+\epsilon_i,$ and jointly normal variables with zero covariance are independent. This gives $\mathbb E_i \theta=\mathbb E_i (\alpha x'_i+\beta x_i)/(\alpha+\beta)=\mathbb E_i (\alpha y+\beta x_i)/(\alpha+\beta).$